# Javascrip default parameter ReferenceError: param is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, referenceerror, default-parameters

I have a function defined to fetch some data. I set default parameters like this:

```
export async function fetchSomeData(limit=10, offset=0) {
    // fetch something
}
```

I import this function in my component and use it like so:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    ...
    let someData = await fetchSomeData() <- This works
    let someData = await fetchSomeData(limit=20, offset=10) <- This doesn't work
    ...
}
```

It works without setting `limit` and `offset`, but when I try to pass new values for `offset` and `limit`, I get an `Unhandled Runtime Error ReferenceError: limit/offset is not defined`. Am I missing something?

Comment: does `fetchSomeData(20, 10)` work? Have you ever called a javascript function with the name of the parameter before? the default value is just that, it doesn't mean you have to now call the function with the name of the parameter :p

Comment: Yup, this works. I'm coming from python where you'd name the param you want to change. Which honestly makes sense, but here if I want to only change "offset" I'd have to know the default value for "limit" and pass that first. Seems even worse when you have a ton of default params to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call an function, you do not "set" the "parameternames".
You just simpliy parse in the Numbers/Data which you want to use inside your function.

So your function call should look like this:

```
let someData = await fetchSomeData(20, 10) <- This should work
```

--

and if you want to use the same parameter (in your case `someData`) again, you do not "re set" the variabletype. You simpily override the existing data.

so in your case your `componentDidMount` will look like this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    ...
    let someData = await fetchSomeData() <- This works
    someData = await fetchSomeData(20, 10) <- This should work
    ...
}
```

Comment: This does work, thanks! I am coming from python where you would name the param. Though it seems a bit counter-intuitive and needlessly redundant because if I just want to pass a value for offset and leave limit as it is, I would have to pass in the default value for limit since it all defaults to positional arguments. What if I had a ton of default params and just wanted to change one of them in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike pyhton, you don't need to specify argument names in the function.

Followings works in python,

```
fetchSomeData(limit=20, offset=10) 
fetchSomeData(offset=10)
```

Followings are way to do same thing in JS,

```
fetchSomeData(20, 10) 
fetchSomeData(undefined, 10)
```

If you want to use a default value for a argument pass `undefined`.

[More Details are here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)